# How to change PHPStorm Project view default filename color

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

How to change PHPStorm Project view default file color from example white to something different? I have looked everywhere in `Color & Fonts` section but nothing worked

Comment: Screenshot please, where I can clearly see which color exactly you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

The Project area colors are defined in IDE theme (`Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Appearance/Theme`). There is no easy way to change foreground of files in the Project tool window. you can, however, change the file background colors using `Settings/Appearance & Behavior/File Colors`: add a color label, choose the desired color and scope, make sure to enable 'Enable file colors' and 'Use in project view'.